# Inject Database Schema by comment into sql file

Tags: intellij-idea

I'd like to specify the database schema for a query by comment. I know that you can do it for files in the settings of intelliJ. But since this information is stored in the intellij configurations (I guess) which aren't shared in our company through git, those information are lost when the project is shared through a VCS like git. And so would other people not get correct validation of the queries.

What I'd like to do is basically something like this:

```
#schema=foo
SELECT * FROM bar;
```

Which would be the same as if you write:

```
SELECT * from foo.bar;
```

For what? Basically just for code completion and validation from intellij that your query is correct and has no syntactic or logical errors. Does anyone know if there's a plugin or hidden functionality? I searched around google but didn't find anything.

E: Nice would be if you can specify those comments for the whole file or only for single queries (first one would be better, second optional)

E2: It maybe looks strange why I don't just write the second example with the schema. But if I don't write that I can load the file to e.g. java and specify the schema dynamically in my source code through the database connection.

Comment: Why don't you just use appropriate <use statement> before the query? Have you tried it? Because DataGrip handles such statements when doing resolve, and code completion. So the script will be valid from both points: stand alone execution and DataGrip resolve.

Comment: Ah good idea. This actually solves my problem. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use appropriate "use statements" in sql file/console. IntelliJ IDEA honors them when doing resolve, and code completion. This is implemented so that you would have the same experience when executing the sole script or within IDE. This way the script will be valid from both points: stand alone execution and IntelliJ IDEA intellisense.